# VB NET user control panel doesn't show up

Tags: vb.net, web-applications, user-controls

I'm not a vb net master, and I got some problem I still can't solve.
I have a main page, when I click on a button I want to display a panel (a web user control I imported in the main page) but it shows nothing.
I think I've done some stupid mistake but I can't get out of it.
Let me show you some code:

- This is the user control:

  ```
      <asp:Panel ID="MainPanelUserMessage" runat="server" Height="278px" Style="z-index: 100; left: 0px;
          position: absolute; top: 0px; background-position: center center; background-attachment: fixed; background-repeat: repeat; font-size: 12px; font-family: Tahoma;" Width="746px">
          <asp:Label ID="LabelTitoloMex" runat="server" Style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px;
              z-index: 100; left: 0px; color: #ffffff; font-family: Verdana, Tahoma; position: absolute;
              top: 0px; background-color: #000000; text-align: center" Text="Messaggio dal supporto tecnico"
              Width="746px"></asp:Label>
          <asp:Label ID="LabelOggettoMex" runat="server" Style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 12px;
              z-index: 105; left: 7px; color: #424242; font-family: Tahoma, Verdana; position: absolute;
              top: 30px" Text="Oggetto:"></asp:Label>
          <asp:TextBox ID="TextOggettoUser" runat="server" MaxLength="100" Style="font-size: 12px;
              z-index: 106; left: 68px; font-family: Tahoma, Verdana; position: absolute; top: 30px;
              text-align: left" ToolTip="Oggetto" Width="660px" ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>
          <asp:TextBox ID="TextMessaggioUser" runat="server" Height="160px" MaxLength="2000" Style="font-size: 12px;
              z-index: 107; left: 9px; font-family: Tahoma, Verdana; position: absolute; top: 60px;
              text-align: left" TextMode="MultiLine" ToolTip="Messaggio" Width="721px" 
              ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>
              <asp:Button ID="okButton" runat="server" Style="font-size: 12px;
              font-family: Tahoma, Verdana; text-align: left" CssClass="style1" 
              Text="Chiudi"> </asp:Button>

          <input id="cbxRemember" type="checkbox" class="style2" />

          <asp:Label ID="lblRemember" runat="server" Style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 12px;
              color: #424242; font-family: Tahoma, Verdana; " 
              Text="Non mostrare più questo messaggio." CssClass="style3"></asp:Label>

      </asp:Panel>
  ```

In the page it will contain the panel it autogenerated this:

```
Protected WithEvents MessaggioUtente1 As Global.System.Web.UI.WebControls.Panel
```

When i click the button this is the code that is executed:

```
PanelClientEnabled = False   //this works and obfuscates background
UserMessage1.Visible = True
```

But the panel doesn't show up.

Any hint?

Comment: where are you declaring `UserMessage1`? Your webform code calls it `MainPanelUserMessage`.

Comment: In main.aspx.designer.vb there is this line of code:

`Protected WithEvents UserMessage1 As Global.GEO_2013.UserMessage`

And inside the method I have no access to MainPanelUserMessage

Comment: Now i get this error when launching the application:

`"The base class includes the field 'UserMessage1', but its type (UserMessage) is not compatible with the type of control (ASP.usermessage_ascx)"`

Comment: S00 .. UserMessage1  is a UserMessage NOT WebControls.Panel !! Declare your panel like : Protected WithEvents UserMessagePanel1  As Global.System.Web.UI.WebControls.Panel  and on click set.Visible=True

Comment: I'm missing something... I have a UserMessage control that somehow has to become a panel in the main class...
So... what should I write in the main.aspx.designer.vb? This is the situation in the main.aspx.designer.vb and still not working... My ideas are really confused...

`Protected WithEvents UserMessage1 As Global.GEO_2013.UserMessage


    Protected WithEvents MainPanelUserMessage As Global.System.Web.UI.WebControls.Panel`